# Elixir: how can I leverage release_handler?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I know there are projects such as exrm which do that for you, and it seem to do it extremely well. However,　I would like to manually play with release_handler for educational purposes, and I find little documentation or articles on the subject.

Comment: The best source I know is: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/release-is-the-word You can also check: http://erlang.org/doc/man/systools.html and http://erlang.org/doc/man/reltool.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the [Learn You Some Erlang article](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/release-is-the-word) about release handling?

Doing upgrades with release handler is both easy and difficult. Easy because once you know all the nitty gritty details it's pretty much automatic. But difficult, because getting all the details right in the first place is quite a task.

I spent quite a lot of time trying to understand how to get the process right and the effect is [builderl](https://github.com/yoonka/builderl), a build system, something like [rebar](https://github.com/basho/rebar), but doing everything from start to finish the [OTP way](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_handling.html).

It's probably not of much use if you are using Elixir, and I don't know much about how the process differs for Elixir. But I can give you a few points that were relevant for Erlang, which you can try to adapt to your case (in the context of `builderl`, as that will allow me to share some code examples).

---

## The bird's view

In general the process is as follows:

1. Create the initial release. This is a compiled version of your project processed with [`systools`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/systools.html#make_script-1) and [`reltool`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/reltool.html#create_target-2) that contains all the folders and files as release handler expects them to be. This is what `builderl` creates in `tmp/rel` for `gmake rel`. It's a self-contained folder also called an [embedded Erlang](http://erlang.org/doc/embedded/embedded_solaris.html) installation. More about it later.
2. Copy the release to the production system, install and start the node.
3. In your development environment make some updates to one or more of the applications running in the release.
4. Create a new version of each application that has changed. Create appropriate [`appup`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/appup.html) files for those applications. Increase the release version.
5. Create the [`relup`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/relup.html) file with [systools](http://erlang.org/doc/man/systools.html#make_relup-3). The easiest way is to have two release versions unpacked alongside each other and the newer version installed and running. Then in the Erlang shell of the new version call `make_relup` referencing the old version of applications from the old version of the release (see snippets at the bottom of the answer).
6. Create the upgrade archive. This is simply a tarball of all applications that have been upgraded, the releases folder, and the release definition file (again snippets at the bottom).
7. Copy the upgrade archive to the production system and unpack with [`release_handler:unpack_release/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/release_handler.html#unpack_release-1). This will unpack the new versions of your applications alongside the old versions in the `lib` folder of the release folder.
8. Then finally install the new version with [`release_handler:install_release/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/release_handler.html#install_release-1).

---

## A release

In order to use release handler the code must be structured in a specific way. The [Releases](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_structure.html) document specifies how a release folder should look like. The [humbundee](https://github.com/amiramix/humbundee) application is an example and here are its folders once `builderl` compiles it and [creates the release using `systools`](https://github.com/yoonka/builderl/blob/master/src/bld_rel.erl#L212) (in `tmp/rel`):

```
> tmp/rel/
bin/
erts-7.2.1/
etc/
lib/
releases/
```

The folders are as follows:

### `lib`

Main folder with applications. Each application may be either without the version suffix (`-Vsn`) or all versions of the same applications have to have the suffix. You can't mix application folders where some of them contain the version suffix and some don't.

But when doing upgrades with release handler all folders must have a proper `-Vsn` suffix, otherwise upgrades don't make sense - upgrades are between versions of applications and Erlang distinguishes the versions by the suffix in the application's folder name.

```
> l tmp/rel/lib/
builderl-0.2.7/
compiler-6.0.2/
deploy-0.0.1/
goldrush-0.1.7/
humbundee-0.0.1/
kernel-4.1.1/
lager-3.0.1/
mnesia-4.13.2/
sasl-2.6.1/
stdlib-2.7/
syntax_tools-1.7/
yajler-0.0.1/
yolf-0.1.1/
```

### `erts-Vsn`

Usually this is a copy of the `erts` folder from where Erlang is installed (`/usr/local/lib/erlang/erts-7.2.1` in my case).

### `releases`

Contains files that define the release. Each file is created slightly differently.

```
> l tmp/rel/releases/
RELEASES
hbd-0.0.1/
start_erl.data
humbundee.rel

> cat release/RELEASES

[{release,"humbundee","hbd-0.0.1","7.2.1",
          [{kernel,"4.1.1","/usr/home/g/work/humbundee/lib/kernel-4.1.1"},
           {stdlib,"2.7","/usr/home/g/work/humbundee/lib/stdlib-2.7"},
           {sasl,"2.6.1","/usr/home/g/work/humbundee/lib/sasl-2.6.1"},
           {yolf,"0.1.1","/usr/home/g/work/humbundee/lib/yolf-0.1.1"},
           {yajler,"0.0.1","/usr/home/g/work/humbundee/lib/yajler-0.0.1"},
           {mnesia,"4.13.2","/usr/home/g/work/humbundee/lib/mnesia-4.13.2"},
           {syntax_tools,"1.7",
                         "/usr/home/g/work/humbundee/lib/syntax_tools-1.7"},
           {compiler,"6.0.2","/usr/home/g/work/humbundee/lib/compiler-6.0.2"},
           {goldrush,"0.1.7","/usr/home/g/work/humbundee/lib/goldrush-0.1.7"},
           {lager,"3.0.1","/usr/home/g/work/humbundee/lib/lager-3.0.1"},
           {humbundee,"0.0.1",
                      "/usr/home/g/work/humbundee/lib/humbundee-0.0.1"}],
          permanent}].

> cat releases/start_erl.data
7.2.1 hbd-0.0.1

> cat tmp/rel/releases/humbundee.rel
%% rel generated at {2016,3,24} {11,9,39}
{release,{"humbundee","hbd-0.0.1"},
         {erts,"7.2.1"},
         [{kernel,"4.1.1"},
          {stdlib,"2.7"},
          {sasl,"2.6.1"},
          {yolf,"0.1.1"},
          {yajler,"0.0.1"},
          {mnesia,"4.13.2"},
          {syntax_tools,"1.7"},
          {compiler,"6.0.2"},
          {goldrush,"0.1.7"},
          {lager,"3.0.1"},
          {humbundee,"0.0.1"}]}.

> l tmp/rel/releases/hbd-0.0.1/
builderl.config
cmd.boot
cmd.data
cmd.rel
cmd.script
hbd.config
humbundee.boot
humbundee.data
humbundee.rel
humbundee.script
start.boot -> humbundee.boot
sys.config -> hbd.config
sys.config.src -> ../../etc/sys.config.src
```

Those files are created automatically by `builderl`, which in turn generates them with the help of Release Handler:

**RELEASES**

Contains the definitions of current and past releases currently available on the system. Can be created with [release_handler:create_RELEASES/4](http://erlang.org/doc/man/release_handler.html#create_RELEASES-4). `builderl` creates it by starting a node with this command (which runs the command and shuts down the node afterwards):

```
run_erl -daemon ../hbd/shell/ ../hbd/log "exec erl ../hbd releases releases/start_erl.data -config releases/$APP_VSN/hbd.config -args_file ../hbd/etc/vm.args -boot releases/$APP_VSN/humbundee -noshell -noinput -eval \"{ok, Cwd} = file:get_cwd(), release_handler:create_RELEASES(Cwd, \\\"releases\\\", \\\"releases/$APP_VSN/humbundee.rel\\\", []), init:stop()\""
```

**start_erl.data**

[Can be created manually](https://github.com/yoonka/builderl/blob/master/src/bld_rel.erl#L254).

**humbundee.rel**

Contains a definition of a release - which applications should be included in the release in which versions. It can be created manually but it's difficult to keep track of the application versions. So, very often it's generated from a more generic file. In case of `builderl` it [generates the `.rel`](https://github.com/yoonka/builderl/blob/master/src/bld_rel.erl#L216) file from a [`reltool.config`](https://github.com/amiramix/humbundee/blob/master/etc/reltool.config) file based on [these `reltool` examples](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/reltool/reltool_examples.html).

### `bin`

Contains links to Erlang executables, script and boot files for releases. In case of `builderl` they are simply [copied from the Erlang installation](https://github.com/yoonka/builderl/blob/master/makefiles/configs#L69).

```
> l tmp/rel/bin/
builderl -> ../lib/builderl-0.2.7
config.esh -> builderl.esh
configure.esh -> builderl.esh
deps.esh -> builderl.esh
init.esh -> builderl.esh
migresia.esh -> builderl.esh
mk_dev.esh -> builderl.esh
mk_rel.esh -> builderl.esh
start.esh -> builderl.esh
stop.esh -> builderl.esh
update_root_dir.esh -> builderl.esh
builderl.esh
ct_run
epmd
erl
escript
run_erl
to_erl
start
cmd.boot
humbundee.boot
start_clean.boot
start_sasl.boot
start.boot
start.script
```

The `.esh` files belong to `builderl` so you can skip them. The executables are copied from `/usr/local/lib/erlang/bin/` (which is system dependent - I am using FreeBSD). The `start*` `boot` and `script` files are also copied from `/usr/local/lib/erlang/bin/` and `cmd.boot` and `humbundee.boot` are simply copied from `tmp/rel/releases/hbd-0.0.1/`.

### `etc`

Used by `builderl` to store configuration files, not required by OTP release handler.

## Snippets

Finally some code snippets to help you work with the release tools:

Create a relup file that upgrades release version 1.1.1 to 9.9.9 (run in the version having the old version of the release alongside, see **The bird's view** at the top of the answer):

```
systools:make_relup("releases/rel-9.9.9/my_release", ["../1.1.1/releases/rel-1.1.1/my_release"], ["../1.1.1/releases/rel-1.1.1/my_release"], [{path, ["../1.1.1/lib/lager-2.6/ebin", "../1.1.1/lib/backup_app-1.1.2/ebin", "../1.1.1/lib/goldrush-2.5/ebin"]}, {outdir, "releases/rel-9.9.9"}]).
```

Create a relup file that upgrades two release versions, 1.1.1 and 2.2.2 to 9.9.9

```
systools:make_relup("releases/rel-9.9.9/my_release", ["../1.1.1/releases/rel-1.1.1/my_release", "../2.2.2/releases/rel-2.2.2/my_release"], ["../1.1.1/releases/rel-1.1.1/my_release", "../2.2.2/releases/rel-2.2.2/my_release"], [{path, ["../1.1.1/lib/lager-2.6/ebin", "../2.2.2/lib/lager-2.4/ebin", "../1.1.1/lib/backup_app-1.1.2/ebin", "../2.2.2/lib/other_app-1.1/ebin"]}, {outdir, "releases/rel-9.9.9"}]).
```

Manually create the release upgrade package

```
tar -czf update_to_rel-9.9.9.tar.gz releases/my_release.rel releases/rel-9.9.9 lib/lager-2.6.1 lib/builderl-0.2.6 lib/deploy-0.4.2 lib/backup_app-2.0.0 lib/other_app-2.5.3
```

Unpack the release upgrade package (after it has been copied to the `releases` folder in the release on the production node):

```
release_handler:unpack_release("rel-9.9.9").
```

Verify the release has been unpacked - the new version should be marked as `unpacked`:

```
release_handler:which_releases().
```

Install the new release:

```
release_handler:install_release("rel-9.9.9").
```

Make it permanent once it's working as expected:

```
release_handler:make_permanent("rel-9.9.9").
```

Rollback the release:

```
release_handler:install_release("rel-1.1.1").
release_handler:remove_release("rel-1.1.1").
```